# Error CS1540/CS0122: Getting keyboard size doesn't work after switching to Unified API

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, uikeyboard

Today I updated to Xamarin.iOS 8.6.0.51 and switched to the new `Unified API`.

Now I want to get the keyboard size (this code worked before):

```
var val = new NSValue (notification.UserInfo.ValueForKey (UIKeyboard.FrameBeginUserInfoKey).Handle);
RectangleF keyboardSize = val.RectangleFValue;
```

With the help of the migration tool the `RectangleF` is converted to `CGRect`, but the errors I'm getting here are

> Error CS1540: Cannot access protected member
>   `Foundation.NSValue.NSValue(System.IntPtr)' via a qualifier of type`
>   Foundation.NSValue'. The qualifier must be of type
>   `MyApp.SomeViewController' or derived from it (CS1540)

and

> Error CS0122: `Foundation.NSValue.NSValue(System.IntPtr)' is
>   inaccessible due to its protection level (CS0122)

How can I solve this? I can delete `new NSValue(...)`, but `RectangleFValue` still doesn't work and I would need a replacement/another way.

**Edit:**

According to jonathanpeppers I modified my code to:

```
NSValue keyboardFrameBegin = (NSValue)notification.UserInfo.ValueForKey (UIKeyboard.FrameBeginUserInfoKey);
CGRect keyboardSize = keyboardFrameBegin.CGRectValue;
```

This doesn't throw an error anymore, but I can't test it further because I'm in the process of migrating to the Unified API and there are still some errors to correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Can you just use a cast:

```
var val = (NSValue)notification.UserInfo.ValueForKey (UIKeyboard.FrameBeginUserInfoKey);
RectangleF keyboardSize = val.RectangleFValue;
```

Only rarely should you have to mess with handles in Xamarin.iOS.

To be absolutely sure what to cast to, debug and see what the underlying type is first:

```
NSObject val = notification.UserInfo.ValueForKey (UIKeyboard.FrameBeginUserInfoKey);
Console.WriteLine("Type: " + val.GetType());
```

Comment: I tried your approach (see my edited question) and it doesn't throw an error at this place. I'll give you the tick if I was able to fully test my application.

Answer (score 1):

The `.ctor(IntPtr)` constructors in `NSObject` could be misused and causes issue later. Also, like @jonathanpeppers mentioned, they were not required for many scenarios (like this one).

Another way to do this (e.g. if you have nothing else but an handle), as [documented here](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/unified/), is to use the `ObjCRuntime.Runtime.GetNSObject<T> (IntPtr)` method. That will ensure the `NSObject`-subclass is created correctly.